# Almost Dedekind (not Noetherian)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

A domain $R$ is a Dedekind domain iff it is integrally closed, Noetherian with Krull dimension at most one. I think they put *Noetherian* in the definition not only to make proofs easier but also because it's important. To see that it's really necessary to have *Noetherian* in the definition do you have an example for me of a domain $R$ which is integrally closed, *not* Noetherian with Krull dimension one? All my examples of domains which are not Noetherian fail to have Krull dimension one.